# "error: underscore lifetimes are unstable" when implementing From<std::sync::PoisonError>

Tags: concurrency, rust

I'm working on a function that looks like this:

```
fn do_stuff(&mut self, a: MyStruct) -> Result<(), MyError> {
    let x = try!(serde_json::to_vec(a));

    let cache = Arc::clone(self.data); // Get shared reference
    {
        let cache = try!(cache.lock()); // Get lock
        cache.push(x);
    }

    /* Do stuff with other resources */

    Ok(())
}
```

Where the definition of `MyError` is:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum MyError {
    Serialization(serde_json::Error),
    Synch(PoisonError<MutexGuard<'_, Vec<u8>>>),
}
```

Before I even get to implementing `From<std::sync::PoisonError>` for `MyError`, the compiler already tells me the definition of the `Synch` variant of my enum is wrong:

```
error: underscore lifetimes are unstable (see issue #44524)
```

The declaration using underscore lifetimes actually came from an earlier hint from the compiler when I was trying to figure out the error I should convert from when the `lock` operation fails. I read the aforementioned issue and that doesn't help me.

What's the full type I should be converting from in order to catch the error from the `Mutex::lock` operation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like so:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum MyError<'a> {
    Serialization(serde_json::Error),
    Synch(PoisonError<MutexGuard<'a, Vec<u8>>>),
}
```

The closest explanation I can find in the book is the section on [Lifetime Annotations in Struct Definitions](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch10-03-lifetime-syntax.html#lifetime-annotations-in-struct-definitions) (`enum`s behave the same way).

The compiler suggesting unstable syntax as a solution is *quite* unfair.

Comment: Thank you, such a simple answer that I overlooked since I was thinking of something more complicated. That being said, something funny happened. Annotating MyError with <'a> had the side effect of making me annotate basically EVERY struct and function I have in my code with another lifetime, since MyError is the overall error for the module. Is this what's "expected", or a symptom of me falling into some design-traps?

Comment: @Dash83: Once you introduce borrows then, yes, you're expected to annotate lifetimes.  It's not necessarily a design trap, just something you have to either accept, or change the design to not use borrows (assuming that's possible).

Comment: while that makes sense (I use lifetimes in some other parts of my code) this made me propagate a new lifetime through my entire codebase, even though this variation of the error only occurs in a single function that is only used in some situations. That's what I found very strange about it all.

Comment: To be honest, I probably wouldn't propagate `PoisonError` at all.  You could have a `Synch` variant *without* the payload.  You need to ask yourself if you're really doing anything worthwhile with the `PoisonError`.

Comment: *The compiler suggesting unstable syntax as a solution is quite unfair.* — I don't think it's really suggesting the unstable syntax. It's more like it doesn't know the lifetime you wanted and so it puts in an underscore as a placeholder. Only recently has the underscore even become a possible concept for a lifetime.

Comment: @Shepmaster: I'm aware, but that doesn't change that it *is now* suggesting unstable syntax.  Users shouldn't have to be aware that this is the case.  :P